# Why scale.ticks(number) from d3 does not work as expect?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts

I get stuck when try to get all tick values from an axis using d3 package. What I did is:

```
const yScale = scaleLinear().domain([44500, 60600]).range([30, 170]);
const yAxis = axisRight(yScale).ticks(5);
const tickValues = yAxis.scale().ticks();
```

And the result of `tickValues` is: `[46000, 48000, 50000, 52000, 54000, 56000, 58000, 60000]` which seems not correct.

I expect: `[45000, 50000, 55000, 60000]` which is generated from the react-stockcharts library. And the above result is what I manually calculate based on the min and max: 44500, 60600 respectively

Does any know what is the problem here ? Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a mistake in the code, I changed to this and it worked as expect:

```
const yScale = scaleLinear().domain([44500, 60600]).range([30, 170]);
const yAxis = axisRight(yScale);
const tickValues = yAxis.scale().ticks(5);
```